# Cygwin offline installer?

Tags: cygwin, installer, file-download

I've tried downloading it several times from several different computers and networks. When I attempt to download it the download gets stuck mid way though. Where can I find a reliable offline installer?

Comment: This has happened to me lots of times over the years when downloading. The whole experience of downloading it via the installer sucks. Whether its the installer or the servers or both ... I don't know nor care - I just want an easy package to download it all in one chunk.

Comment: different computers & connections. At university, at home, at work...

Comment: Not doing this in order to revoke the downvote, but you're right, my rant was inappropriate, revised. :)

Comment: Cygwin is a good UNIX-like dev environment for Windows, but really rubbish for installation and setup on Windows. They should really improve the infrastructure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a **modified apt-cyg** that runs the installer from the local archive.
It really should be submitted as a patch, but never had the time to clean it up, so here goes.

**Features**

- Offline install
- Set mirror
- Cache package so later installs can be faster
- Force re-instalation even when package is installed
- Supports setup.ini / setup.bz2 /
- Use downloader of your choice to obtain the packages (we use rsync as default)
- Scans cache for leftover, uses packages from failed installs of setup.exe as much as possible.  (just make sure that you specify the cache folder when installing from setup.exe)

### Download

http://pastebin.com/SSTZ4ATL
or see lower part of this answer

### Usage:

Lets say you want your local repo at `c:/archive/cygwin/` or `/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/`
if that matters.

Lets setup a repo, no matter what the download speed is.
Adjust the mirror according to where you live, or is the fastest accessable.

```
cat > /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
#
###
# Choose mirror that is on http://www.cygwin.com/mirrors.html
#
# "ftp://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/"
# "ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/lang/cygwin/"
# "http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/"
#
# Old
# "http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/mirrors.lst"
###
rsync --partial -va rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/cygwin/release/ /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/release/
#
#/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin
EOF
```

Then run the following

```
chmod +x /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh
```

From now on, a simple `/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/sync-with-cygwin-mirror.sh`
will update your local repo to the latest and greatest.

Next, setup the enviroment vars, so setup.exe will not get confused.

```
cat > /etc/setup/last-cache <<"EOF"
C:\archive\cygwin
EOF
```

Setup the default mirror, to whatever is fastest for you

```
cat > /etc/setup/last-mirror <<"EOF"
ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin
EOF
```

then try it out!

```
apt-cyg find <pacakge name>
apt-cyg install <package name>
```

Example output of typical install session (I used `--force` here as this package was aready installed. You do not need it. Just for showing how to use, here)

```
$ apt-cyg install man --force
Working directory is /cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin
Mirror is ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin
We are using the cache as package source.

Installing man
Found package man
DBG:pwd=[/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin]pkg=[man]file=[man-1.6f-1.tar.bz2]mirror=[ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin]install=[release/man/
man-1.6f-1.tar.bz2]
DBG:169:pwd=[/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin/release/man]pkg=[man]file=[man-1.6f-1.tar.bz2]mirror=[ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin]insta
ll=[release/man/man-1.6f-1.tar.bz2]
Checking md5hash [9a34daa8d8dfbf9222035b4f1952ab1d] == [9a34daa8d8dfbf9222035b4f1952ab1d]
Unpacking...
Package man requires the following packages, installing:
bash libgcc1 bzip2 coreutils gawk groff gzip less cygwin
Package bash is already installed, skipping
Package libgcc1 is already installed, skipping
Package bzip2 is already installed, skipping
Package coreutils is already installed, skipping
Package gawk is already installed, skipping
Package groff is already installed, skipping
Package gzip is already installed, skipping
Package less is already installed, skipping
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Package man installed
```

Notice that **because we aready had a local copy, it did not connect to the network**, and instead, used the known copy that we had. Even if we do not know if we have the package, **as long as the package is located somewhere in the sub directory of cache, apt-cyg will find it**, and use md5sum hash to validate if the package is broken or not.

### Help:

```
apt-cyg: Installs and removes Cygwin packages.
  "apt-cyg install <package names>" to install packages
  "apt-cyg remove <package names>" to remove packages
  "apt-cyg update" to update setup.ini
  "apt-cyg show" to show installed packages
  "apt-cyg find <patterns>" to find packages matching patterns
  "apt-cyg describe <patterns>" to describe packages matching patterns
  "apt-cyg packageof <commands or files>" to locate parent packages
Options:
  --mirror, -m <url> : set mirror
  --cache, -c <dir>  : set cache
  --file, -f <file>  : read package names from file
  --noupdate, -u     : don't update setup.ini from mirror
  --localdiskcache   : Use local cache as source, if available. Used for offline instalation.
  --force            : Force re-installing package. USE WITH CAUTION AND CARE!
  --ForceUpdate      : Force re-initalizeing setup.ini.
  --help
  --version
  --find-setup-exe   :experemental
```

And here is the source, in case pastebin is down

### source

```
#!/bin/bash
# apt-cyg: install tool for cygwin similar to debian apt-get
# 
# Copyright (C) 2005-9, Stephen Jungels
# Modified by GreenFox
# 
# This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
# modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
# of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
# 
# This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
# 
# (http://www.fsf.org/licensing/licenses/gpl.html)

# this script requires some packages

WGET=`which wget 2> /dev/null`
BZIP2=`which bzip2 2> /dev/null`
TAR=`which tar 2> /dev/null`
GAWK=`which awk 2> /dev/null`
if test "-$WGET-" = "--" || test "-$BZIP2-" = "--" || test "-$TAR-" = "--" \
  || test "-$GAWK-" = "--"
then
  echo You must install wget, tar, gawk and bzip2 to use apt-cyg.
  exit 1
fi


function usage()
{
  echo apt-cyg: Installs and removes Cygwin packages.
  echo "  \"apt-cyg install <package names>\" to install packages"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg remove <package names>\" to remove packages"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg update\" to update setup.ini"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg show\" to show installed packages"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg find <patterns>\" to find packages matching patterns"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg describe <patterns>\" to describe packages matching patterns"
  echo "  \"apt-cyg packageof <commands or files>\" to locate parent packages"
  echo "Options:"
  echo "  --mirror, -m <url> : set mirror"
  echo "  --cache, -c <dir>  : set cache"
  echo "  --file, -f <file>  : read package names from file"
  echo "  --noupdate, -u     : don't update setup.ini from mirror"
  echo "  --localdiskcache   : Use local cache as source, if available. Used for offline instalation."
  echo "  --force            : Force re-installing package. USE WITH CAUTION AND CARE!"
  echo "  --ForceUpdate      : Force re-initalizeing setup.ini.  "
  echo "  --help"
  echo "  --version"
  echo "  --find-setup-exe   :experemental"
}



function version()
{
  echo "apt-cyg version 0.58 custombuild"
  echo "Written by Stephen Jungels"
  echo "Modified by GreenFox"
  echo "Copyright (c) 2005-2012.  Released under the GPL."
}

function findsetupexe()
{
  echo "Attempting to load setup.exe, or loading from network..."
  [ -e "${cache}/setup.exe" ] && echo "Try using [ ${cache}/setup.exe ]"
}

function findworkspace()
{
  # default working directory and mirror
  
  mirror="ftp://mirror.mcs.anl.gov/pub/cygwin"
  mirror="ftp://ftp.iij.ad.jp/pub/cygwin"
  cache="/cygdrive/c/archive/cygwin"
  # Note: path should be in unix format.
  
  # work wherever setup worked last, if possible
  
  if test -e /etc/setup/last-cache
  then
    tmp="`head -1 /etc/setup/last-cache`"
    cache="`cygpath -au "$tmp"`"
  fi
  
  if test -e /etc/setup/last-mirror
  then
    mirror="`head -1 /etc/setup/last-mirror`"
  fi
  if test "$localdiskcache" == "1"
  then
    echo Working directory is $cache
    echo Mirror is $mirror
    echo We are using the cache as package source.
    cd "$cache"
  else
    # Old method that uses network. Left for compatibility purpose.
    mirrordir="`echo "$mirror" | sed -e "s/:/%3a/g" -e "s:/:%2f:g"`"
    echo Working directory is $cache
    echo Mirror is $mirror
    mkdir -p "$cache/$mirrordir"
    cd "$cache/$mirrordir"
  fi
}


function getsetup() 
{
  if test "$noscripts" == "0" -a "$noupdate" == "0" -a "$localdiskcache" == "0"
  then
    touch "setup.ini"
    mv "setup.ini" "setup.ini-save"
    wget -N "$mirror/setup.bz2"
    if test -e "setup.bz2" && test $? -eq 0
    then
      bunzip2 "setup.bz2"
      mv "setup" "setup.ini"
      echo "Updated setup.ini"
    else
      wget -N "$mirror/setup.ini"
      if test -e setup.ini && test $? -eq 0
      then
        echo "Updated setup.ini"
      else
        mv "setup.ini-save" "setup.ini"
        echo "Error updating setup.ini, reverting"
      fi
    fi
  fi
}


function checkpackages()
{
  if test "-$packages-" = "--"
  then
    echo Nothing to do, exiting
    exit 0
  fi
}
function apt-cyg-func-install(){
  for pkg in $packages
    do
      already="`grep -c "^$pkg " /etc/setup/installed.db`"
      if test $already -ge 1 -a "$forceinstall" == "0"
      then
        echo "Package $pkg is already installed, skipping"
        continue
      fi
      echo ""
      echo Installing $pkg
      # look for package and save desc file
      mkdir -p "release/$pkg"
      cat setup.ini | awk > "release/$pkg/desc" -v package="$pkg" \
        'BEGIN{RS="\n\n@ "; FS="\n"} {if ($1 == package) {desc = $0; px++}} \
         END{if (px == 1 && desc != "") print desc; else print "Package not found"}' 
    
      desc=`cat "release/$pkg/desc"`
      if test "-$desc-" = "-Package not found-"
      then
        echo Package $pkg not found or ambiguous name, exiting
        rm -r "release/$pkg"
        exit 1
      fi
      echo Found package $pkg

      # download and unpack the bz2 file

      # pick the latest version, which comes first
      install=`cat "release/$pkg/desc" | awk '/^install: / { print $2; exit }'` 

      if test "-$install-" = "--"
      then
        echo "Could not find \"install\" in package description: obsolete package?"
        echo "Debug output of [$(realpath "release/$pkg/desc")]"
        echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
        cat "release/$pkg/desc"
        echo "-----------------------------------------------------"
        exit 1
      fi
      file=`basename $install`
      if test "$localdiskcache" == "1"
      then
############################################
# This section needs refactoring. TODO
############################################
        echo "DBG:pwd=[`pwd`]pkg=[$pkg]file=[$file]mirror=[$mirror]install=[$install]"
        cd "$cache"
        cd "release/$pkg"
        if ! test -e "$file"
        then
          # Scan dir for matching name
          echo "Scanning cache for leftover..."
          local leftover_file="`find "$cache" -name "$file" |head -n 1`";
          if test "$leftover_file" == "" ; then
            #
            echo "Package $pkg missing from cache. Downloading file from mirror $mirror."
            wget -nc $mirror/$install
            # The mirror might not have the file.TODO.
          else
            echo "Trying to use [$leftover_file] as alternative to [$file]"
            file="$leftover_file";
          fi
        fi
        echo "DBG:169:pwd=[`pwd`]pkg=[$pkg]file=[$file]mirror=[$mirror]install=[$install]"

          digest="`cat "desc" | awk '/^install: / { print $4; exit }'`";
          digactual="`md5sum "$file" | awk '{print $1}'`";
          echo "Checking md5hash [$digest] == [$digactual] "
          if test "$digest" != "$digactual" ;
          then
            echo "Package $pkg in cache data is broken, partial, or empty. Downloading file from mirror."
            wget -c $mirror/$install
          fi
          digactual=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
############################################
      else
        cd "release/$pkg"
        wget -nc $mirror/$install
        digest=`cat "desc" | awk '/^install: / { print $4; exit }'` 
        digactual=`md5sum $file | awk '{print $1}'`
      fi
  
      if ! test $digest = $digactual
      then
        echo "MD5 sum did not match, exiting"
        exit 1
      fi
    
      echo "Unpacking..."
      #####
      # Dumps to root dir. We need to add code for chroot creating options
      ####
      cat "$file" | bunzip2 | tar > "/etc/setup/$pkg.lst" xvf - -C /
      gzip -f "/etc/setup/$pkg.lst"
      cd ../..
    
    
      # update the package database
    
      cat /etc/setup/installed.db | awk > /tmp/awk.$$ -v pkg="$pkg" -v bz=$file \
        '{if (ins != 1 && pkg < $1) {print pkg " " bz " 0"; ins=1}; print $0} \
         END{if (ins != 1) print pkg " " bz " 0"}'
      mv /etc/setup/installed.db /etc/setup/installed.db-save
      mv /tmp/awk.$$ /etc/setup/installed.db
    
    
      # recursively install required packages
    
      echo > /tmp/awk.$$ '/^requires: / {s=gensub("(requires: )?([^ ]+) ?", "\\2 ", "g", $0); print s}'
      requires=`cat "release/$pkg/desc" | awk -f /tmp/awk.$$`
    
      warn=0
      if ! test "-$requires-" = "--"
      then
        echo Package $pkg requires the following packages, installing:
        echo $requires
        for package in $requires
        do
          already=`grep -c "^$package " /etc/setup/installed.db`
          if test $already -ge 1
          then
            echo Package $package is already installed, skipping
            continue
          fi
          apt-cyg --noscripts install $package
          if ! test $? = 0 ; then warn=1; fi
        done
      fi
      if ! test $warn = 0
      then
        echo "Warning: some required packages did not install, continuing"
      fi
    
      # run all postinstall scripts
    
      pis=`ls "/etc/postinstall/*.sh" 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
      if test $pis -gt 0 && ! test $noscripts -eq 1
      then
        echo Running postinstall scripts
        for script in "/etc/postinstall/*.sh"
        do
          $script
          mv $script $script.done
        done
      fi
      
      echo Package $pkg installed
      done

}

function main(){
  # process options
  local noscripts=0
  local noupdate=0
  local file=""
  local dofile=0
  local command=""
  local filepackages=""
  local packages=""
  local localdiskcache=1
  local forceinstall=0

# use vars = [ noscripts noupdate localdiskcache forceinstall file dofile command packages ]
  while test $# -gt 0
  do
  case "$1" in
    --mirror|-m)
      echo "$2" > /etc/setup/last-mirror
      shift ; shift
    ;;
    --cache|-c)
      cygpath -aw "$2" > /etc/setup/last-cache
      shift ; shift
    ;;
    --noscripts)
      noscripts=1
      shift
    ;;
    --noupdate|-u)
      noupdate=1
      shift
    ;;
    --ForceUpdate)
      noupdate=0
      localdiskcache=0
      shift
    ;;
    --localdiskcache)
      localdiskcache=1
      shift
    ;;
    --force)
      forceinstall=1
      shift
    ;;
    --help)
      usage
      exit 0
    ;;
    --version)
      version
      exit 0
    ;;
    --find-setup-exe)
      findsetupexe
      exit 0
    ;;
    --file|-f)
      if ! test "-$2-" = "--"
      then
        file="$2"
        dofile=1
        shift
      else
        echo 1>&2 No file name provided, ignoring $1
      fi
      shift
    ;;
    update|show|find|describe|packageof|install|remove)
      if test "-$command-" = "--"
      then
        command=$1
      else
        packages="$packages $1"
      fi
      shift
    ;;
    *)
      packages="$packages $1"
      shift
    ;;
  esac
  done
  ######################################################
  # Done reading the options. Now process accordingly
  ######################################################
  if test $dofile = 1
  then
    if test -f "$file"
    then
      filepackages="$filepackages `cat "$file" | awk '{printf "%s ", $0}'`"
    else
      echo File $file not found, skipping
    fi
    packages="$packages $filepackages"
  fi

  case "$command" in
  update)
    findworkspace
    getsetup
  ;;
  show)
    echo 1>&2 The following packages are installed:
    cat /etc/setup/installed.db | awk '/[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0/ {print $1}'
  ;;
  find)
    checkpackages
    findworkspace
    getsetup
    for pkg in $packages
    do
      echo ""
      echo Searching for installed packages matching $pkg:
      awk '/[^ ]+ [^ ]+ 0/ {if ($1 ~ query) print $1}' query="$pkg" /etc/setup/installed.db
      echo ""
      echo Searching for installable packages matching $pkg:
      cat setup.ini | awk -v query="$pkg" \
        'BEGIN{RS="\n\n@ "; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"} {if ($1 ~ query) {print $1}}'
    done
  ;;
  describe)
    checkpackages
    findworkspace
    getsetup
    for pkg in $packages
    do
      echo ""
      cat setup.ini | awk -v query="$pkg" \
        'BEGIN{RS="\n\n@ "; FS="\n"; ORS="\n"} {if ($1 ~ query) {print $0 "\n"}}'
    done
  ;;
  packageof)
    checkpackages
    for pkg in $packages
    do
      key=`which "$pkg" 2>/dev/null | sed "s:^/::"`
      if test "-$key-" = "--"
      then
        key="$pkg"
      fi
      for manifest in "/etc/setup/*.lst.gz"
      do
        found=`cat "$manifest" | gzip -d | grep -c "$key"`
        if test $found -gt 0
        then
          package=`echo "$manifest" | sed -e "s:/etc/setup/::" -e "s/.lst.gz//"`
          echo Found $key in the package $package
        fi
      done
    done
  ;;
  install)
    checkpackages
    findworkspace
    getsetup
    apt-cyg-func-install
    ;;
  remove)
    checkpackages
    for pkg in $packages
    do
      already=`grep -c "^$pkg " /etc/setup/installed.db`
      if test $already = 0
      then
        echo Package $pkg is not installed, skipping
        continue
      fi
      dontremove="cygwin coreutils gawk bzip2 tar wget bash"
      for req in $dontremove
      do
        if test "-$pkg-" = "-$req-"
        then
          echo apt-cyg cannot remove package $pkg, exiting
          exit 1
        fi
      done
      if ! test -e "/etc/setup/$pkg.lst.gz"
      then
        echo Package manifest missing, cannot remove $pkg.  Exiting
        exit 1
     fi
      echo Removing $pkg
      # run preremove scripts
      if test -e "/etc/preremove/$pkg.sh"
      then
        "/etc/preremove/$pkg.sh"
        rm "/etc/preremove/$pkg.sh"
      fi
      cat "/etc/setup/$pkg.lst.gz" | gzip -d | awk '/[^\/]$/ {print "rm -f \"/" $0 "\""}' | sh
      rm "/etc/setup/$pkg.lst.gz"
      rm -f /etc/postinstall/$pkg.sh.done
      cat /etc/setup/installed.db | awk > /tmp/awk.$$ -v pkg="$pkg" '{if (pkg != $1) print $0}'
      mv /etc/setup/installed.db /etc/setup/installed.db-save
      mv /tmp/awk.$$ /etc/setup/installed.db
      echo Package $pkg removed
    done
  ;;
  *)
    usage
  ;;
esac

}
main "$@"
```

Answer (score 3):

I usually use the "download to local directory" option in the standard installer, and select the packages I want in a base installation.  That downloads the packages I want but doesn't install, and I can copy that package directory to a network share or thumbdrive.  Add a copy of the Cygwin *setup.exe* to that local directory, and you've got yourself an offline installer.

The disadvantage to this method is that your offline packages aren't kept up to date.  But you can always re-run the setup to download and install updated packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a standalone Cygwin installer using [pmycg](http://pmcyg.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

I was having some trouble with apt-cyg setup.ini

I had to change the getsetup method in apt-cyg in order to get everything working.

```
function getsetup()
{
  if test "$noscripts" == "0" -a "$noupdate" == "0"
  then
    touch setup.ini
    mv setup.ini setup.ini-save
    wget -N $mirror/setup.bz2
    if test -e setup.bz2 && test $? -eq 0
    then
      bunzip2 setup.bz2
      mv setup setup.ini
      echo Updated setup.ini
    else
      if [ `arch` == "x86_64" ]
      then
        echo using x86_64
        arch=x86_64
      else
        echo using x86
        arch=x86
      fi
      wget -N $mirror/$arch/setup.ini
      if test -e setup.ini && test $? -eq 0
      then
        echo Updated setup.ini
      else
        mv setup.ini-save setup.ini
        echo Error updating setup.ini, reverting
      fi
    fi
  fi
}
```

Comment: here is a pastebin of the whole file: http://pastebin.com/ZhSXC393