# I am trying to install cygwin on my windows XP machine. But I am unable to do so

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin

I am on windows XP. I am trying to install cygwin on my machine. But the setup doesn't load any mirror list. Does anybody know a specific URL to install it?

Comment: Who downvoted this question?  It is fine.  Dear Trolls: Please go back to your mother's basement.

Answer (score 1):

Install it by running [setup.exe](http://www.cygwin.com/setup.exe).
Also if you have any problems in installing Cygwin let me know.

Hope it helps.

[List](http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/mirrors.lst) of mirrors.

Comment: I tried that only, but I am unable to get the list of mirrors. I guess it can be a firewall issue

Comment: I have updated with list of mirrors available at Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

If the mirrors are your problem here are 2 post about Offline Cygwin installs

[Cygwin offline installer?](https://superuser.com/questions/99198/cygwin-offline-installer)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661939/where-can-i-download-an-offline-installer-of-cygwin